# I'm getting Cannot find module 'aurelia-http-client'. even it was in the config file and jspm_packages. do I need to do any thing else

Tags: node.js, aurelia, jspm

I'm using aurelia with jspm and I was planning to use aurelia-http-client.
To install it I have run

> jspm install aurelia-http-client

as I can see it updated my jspm depencies like below

```
"aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
"aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
"aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
"aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.0-beta.2.0.0",
"aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
"aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
"aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
```

in the config file update like below

```
"npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
"aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@1.0.0-beta.2.0.0",
"aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
"aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
```

but when I run gulp watch I'm getting

Cannot find module 'aurelia-http-client'

and its give an error in the browser also :(

Comment: did you do jspm install aurelia-http-client?

Comment: yes I did. `"npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.0-beta.2.0.0"` its added to package.json also.

Comment: sorry to ask this, but you did also npm install right?

Comment: yeah I did. by downgrading the I have fix the issue. because my some js lib are from aurelia  `1.0.0-beta.1.2.0` version

Comment: but after that I'm getting browser error which saying that is coudn't find

Comment: error is below `Unhandled rejection TypeError: _this.XHRType is not a constructor`

Answer (score 0):

By downgrading the version of aurelia-http-client it help to solve the issue I run the below command

```
jspm install aurelia-http-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.0
```

after that need to delete jspm_packges and rerun the `jspm install`